# How to use android .aar in basic for android (b4a)

Tags: java, android, aar, vb4android

I tried wrapping `class.jar` and adding res folder and manifest file to my b4a project. But, unfortunately, b4a can not find declared services and receivers in the manifest file. What is the proper way to make a wrapper for arr files?

Comment: The B4A community forum is the best place to start, with the issue of wrapping aar files a tutorial is here [link]https://www.b4x.com/android/forum/threads/create-an-aar-archive-from-a-third-party-library.68357/#content[/link]